# Attach focus event on dynamic textarea

Tags: jquery, html, events, focus, textarea

I want to attach a focus event on dynamically created `textarea` element. I have created a fiddle below which describes my problem. When I click on 'click' link another text area is created. It doesn't get focus event.

```
$("textarea").on("focus", function(){
    alert("textarea focus");
    $(this).blur();
});

$("a").click(function(){
    $("div").append("<textarea>2</textarea>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LepvD/2/

How can I add focus event on dynamic textarea? I want to avoid again attaching focus again and again for each new element

Comment: @reyaner, thats the solution, I am sure no body copied them

Comment: 3 times same alert... what a coincidence.. never mind.

Comment: @reyaner - Did you look at the jsfiddle? The alert is included there. They probbably copied that code and changed it accordingly.

Comment: ahh nope, i didnt... makes sens now, they copied it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here since your `textarea` is dynamically created:

```
$(document).on("focus","textarea", function(){
    alert("textarea focus");
    $(this).blur();
});
```

It will helps you to bind the `focus` event on these newly added `textarea`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LepvD/5/)**

Comment: Will it work for elements created dynamically even inside an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

you shouild use event delegation.use:

```
 $(document).on("focus","textarea", function(){
    alert("textarea focus");
    $(this).blur();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LepvD/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use **Delegated events**, as they have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating textarea dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

```
$("div").on("focus", "textarea", function(){
    alert("textarea focus");
    $(this).blur();
});
```

<kbd><kbd><kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LepvD/2/)</kbd></kbd></kbd>